# File ended while scanning use of \__siunitx_table_collect_braced:n

Tags: longtable, landscape

I'm trying to compile this code aimed to create a long table with landscape view, but i receive this error.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{float,lipsum,subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox,ragged2e}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, dcolumn, 
    makecell,                          
    longtable, tabularx,pdflscape}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}  
\renewcommand\theadgape{}                      

\usepackage{mathtools,array,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} 
\usepackage[justification = centering]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newsavebox\ltmcbox
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add 
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
    deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
    escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    firstnumber=1000,                % start line enumeration with line 1000
    frame=single,                      % adds a frame around the code
    keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
    language=Octave,                 % the language of the code
    morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\filcenter}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
{0pt}{30pt}{12pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
%\setstretch{1.5}
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%




\begin{document}

    %%APPENDIX A    
%\chapter[]{}
\begin{appendices}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{S[table-format=8.0]S[table-format=7.0]S[table-format=7.0]c S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=-4.0]S[table-format=-4.0]S[table-format=-4.0]}
        \caption{Summary of data collected in the field for MAC fm. $R_{site(obs)}$ is the . For each geomechanical survey, its code, coordinates (in term of Longitude and
            Latitute, according to the Gauss-Boaga system), elevation, geological formation, lithology, corrected median value, interquartile range and GSI are reported. Used abbreviations: Long: longitude; Lat: latitude; Geol. fm: geological formation; Sst: sandstone; Sltst: siltstone;W.G: weathering grade.}
        \label{tab:summary_camp_MAC} \\
        \toprule
        {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} & {\thead{Elev.\\(m.a.s.l.)}}& {\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}}  & {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)}$}} & {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}}& {\textbf{$ Mv\%$}} & {\textbf{GSI}} &{\textbf{{W.G}}\\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{}\\        
        \toprule
        {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} & {\thead{Elev.\\(m.a.s.l.)}}& {\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}}  & {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)}$}} & {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}}& {\textbf{$ Mv\%$}} & {\textbf{GSI}} &{\textbf{{W.G}}\\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        \multicolumn{12}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        20160007    &   1607690 &   4885250 &   199 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.4    &   3.9 &   8.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20160008    &   1616420 &   4892160 &   191 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   13.9    &   32.7    &   35  &   2   \\
        20160009    &   1617450 &   4892970 &   144 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   6.4 &   12.3    &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20160028    &   1642450 &   4867020 &   116 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   11.8    &   4.8 &   33.3    &   45  &   3   \\
        20160054    &   1607510 &   4895540 &   169 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.4 &   5.8 &   26.0    &   40  &   3   \\
        20160055    &   1651750 &   4855650 &   154 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   6.4 &   3.5 &   60.5    &   15  &   4   \\
        20160058    &   1599670 &   4899700 &   184 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.1    &   10.2    &   24.3    &   35  &   2   \\
        20160064    &   1613750 &   4875080 &   265 &   MAC &   100 &       &   8.9 &   6.4 &   40.5    &   40  &   3   \\
        20160065    &   1628850 &   4875430 &   239 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.9    &   9.1 &   18.0    &   50  &   2   \\
        20160067    &   1626270 &   4880370 &   246 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.9    &   7.9 &   31.5    &   40  &   3   \\
        20160089    &   1579370 &   4907480 &   488 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.3    &   6.3 &   18.5    &   35  &   2   \\
        20160094    &   1626920 &   4864650 &   553 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   15.4    &   4.9 &   11.8    &   45  &   3   \\
        20160099    &   1615920 &   4891250 &   565 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.8    &   10.3    &   29.5    &   40  &   3   \\
        20160102    &   1608230 &   4883910 &   650 &   MAC &       &       &   11.3    &   13.4    &   30.3    &   50  &   2   \\
        20160103    &   1630270 &   4874830 &   888 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.2    &   9.8 &   27.3    &   40  &   2   \\
        20160111    &   1637300 &   4866700 &   714 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.3    &   5.8 &   2.5 &   50  &   2   \\
        20160116    &   1635020 &   4887380 &   755 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.6    &   7.6 &   5.8 &   45  &   2   \\
        20160125    &   1638850 &   4861050 &   462 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.9    &   9.4 &   55.5    &   35  &   3   \\
        20160126    &   1632580 &   4875200 &   646 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   9.9 &   16.3    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160132    &   1627950 &   4879380 &   243 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.7    &   13.7    &   9.0 &   70  &   2   \\
        20160140    &   1629620 &   4876660 &   649 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.4    &   6.2 &   23.3    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160161    &   1612630 &   4892280 &   575 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   10.6    &   8.1 &   37.8    &   40  &   2   \\
        20160179    &   1633200 &   4874750 &   186 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   16.5    &   22.3    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160180    &   1629130 &   4877660 &   371 &   MAC &   20  &       &   11.7    &   13.4    &   36.8    &   35  &   2   \\
        20160187    &   1609870 &   4886470 &   355 &   MAC &   100 &       &   34.5    &   9.0 &   1.3 &   60  &   2   \\
        20160189    &   1616110 &   4883040 &   299 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.9    &   3.1 &   0.3 &   60  &   2   \\
        20160190    &   1639440 &   4884930 &   337 &   MAC &       &   30  &   8.6 &   6.1 &   46.5    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160192    &   1621280 &   4882190 &   435 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.3    &   8.3 &   0.3 &   60  &   2   \\
        20160199    &   1617480 &   4892980 &   616 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   7.4 &   1.3 &   50  &   2   \\
        20160212    &   1623080 &   4886120 &   588 &   MAC &   95  &       &   15.6    &   3.7 &   3.3 &   40  &   2   \\
        20160215    &   1635030 &   4871590 &   486 &   MAC &   50  &   10  &   15.3    &   6.2 &   7.0 &   35  &   3   \\
        20160216    &   1633810 &   4873860 &   833 &   MAC &   100 &       &   14.2    &   5.9 &   7.5 &   35  &   2   \\
        20160228    &   1611490 &   4888050 &   666 &   MAC &   90  &       &   28.7    &   17.5    &   4.5 &   60  &   2   \\
        20160230    &   1611900 &   4886400 &   842 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.4    &   15.2    &   1.8 &   50  &   2   \\
        20160234    &   1649360 &   4859070 &   671 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   7.4 &   0.0 &   50  &   2   \\
        20160240    &   1628280 &   4885520 &   1014    &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   10.4    &   6.3 &   50  &   2   \\
        20160245    &   1606850 &   4886800 &   553 &   MAC &   95  &       &   31.6    &   10.3    &   1.3 &   50  &   2   \\
        20160248    &   1604840 &   4897570 &   931 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.7    &   6.5 &   10.0    &   50  &   2   \\
        20160252    &   1604300 &   4899930 &   725 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.2    &   11.4    &   1.3 &   55  &   3   \\
        20160256    &   1610880 &   4872490 &   616 &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   24.0    &   7.6 &   20.5    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160257    &   1603610 &   4889240 &   394 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.0    &   4.2 &   0.0 &   65  &   1   \\
        20160264    &   1617530 &   4890220 &   718 &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.3    &   6.7 &   0.0 &   60  &   2   \\
        20160267    &   1632780 &   4889010 &   1029    &   MAC &   40  &       &   13.7    &   17.3    &   24.3    &   40  &       \\
        20160272    &   1636910 &   4887220 &   613 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.8    &   8.0 &   2.3 &   55  &   2   \\
        20160277    &   1589240 &   4878450 &   725 &   MAC &   100 &       &   10.5    &   7.2 &   24.3    &   30  &   3   \\
        20160278    &   1589630 &   4878030 &   717 &   MAC &   100 &       &   11.3    &   6.1 &   22.3    &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20160279    &   1589360 &   4878090 &   586 &   MAC &       &       &   14.9    &   9.7 &   21.8    &   -9999   &   1   \\
        20160280    &   1589200 &   4878190 &   506 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.8    &   4.1 &   1.5 &   50  &   2   \\
        20160281    &   1588690 &   4878380 &   439 &   MAC &   100 &       &   9.1 &   6.2 &   35.5    &   30  &   3   \\
        20160283    &   1586320 &   4881360 &   310 &   MAC &   100 &       &   17.7    &   15.0    &   16.0    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160284    &   1585980 &   4881540 &   393 &   MAC &   80  &       &   17.3    &   5.5 &   2.8 &   45  &   2   \\
        20160286    &   1588290 &   4878570 &   563 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.1    &   6.2 &   1.5 &   55  &   2   \\
        20170292    &   1592500 &   4892430 &   784 &   MAC &       &       &   19.2    &   7.8 &   1.8 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170293    &   1593630 &   4895890 &   297 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   7.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170294    &   1592590 &   4896460 &   622 &   MAC &   100 &       &   31.0    &   6.9 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170295    &   1592350 &   4896370 &   699 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.7    &   9.9 &   3.5 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170296    &   1592380 &   4905810 &   224 &   MAC &   100 &       &   29.0    &   8.0 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170297    &   1592400 &   4907000 &   875 &   MAC &   70  &       &   15.0    &   13.3    &   31.8    &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170298    &   1592170 &   4906530 &   733 &   MAC &   70  &       &   10.1    &   12.3    &   45.3    &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170299    &   1594910 &   4891490 &   836 &   MAC &   90  &       &   29.7    &   9.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170300    &   1585800 &   4887720 &   702 &   MAC &   90  &       &   31.1    &   6.3 &   2.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170302    &   1584720 &   4886610 &   574 &   MAC &   75  &       &   30.0    &   11.6    &   3.8 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170303    &   1592340 &   4891340 &   355 &   MAC &   60  &       &   27.7    &   11.9    &   5.5 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170304    &   1584520 &   4885990 &   267 &   MAC &   85  &       &   18.6    &   5.0 &   4.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170305    &   1579960 &   4888640 &   249 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.0    &   6.8 &   2.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170306    &   1582470 &   4887480 &   616 &   MAC &   100 &       &   12.8    &   3.2 &   1.3 &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170311    &   1572640 &   4900500 &   684 &   MAC &   85  &   15  &   32.3    &   17.0    &   9.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170312    &   1569670 &   4900420 &   1136    &   MAC &   95  &       &   41.5    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170313    &   1568040 &   4908720 &   1325    &   MAC &   90  &       &   38.4    &   13.1    &   3.8 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170314    &   1569090 &   4909490 &   1298    &   MAC &   80  &   20  &   29.2    &   9.3 &   6.8 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170315    &   1570460 &   4907080 &   788 &   MAC &   50  &       &   22.5    &   11.5    &   1.8 &   -9999   &   1   \\
        20170319    &   1568360 &   4905170 &   398 &   MAC &   70  &   30  &   7.2 &   5.4 &   45.8    &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170320    &   1587250 &   4908030 &   381 &   MAC &   90  &   10  &   24.0    &   13.8    &   19.8    &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170321    &   1577010 &   4912650 &   855 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.0    &   6.1 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170322    &   1569040 &   4911210 &   823 &   MAC &   95  &       &   12.9    &   5.0 &   12.0    &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170324    &   1567700 &   4910090 &   637 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.9    &   7.3 &   0.5 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170325    &   1575160 &   4913620 &   574 &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.5    &   16.8    &   16.8    &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170326    &   1578770 &   4913330 &   967 &   MAC &   100 &       &   21.7    &   12.8    &   2.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170327    &   1583430 &   4909340 &   911 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.5    &   7.4 &   0.8 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170328    &   1564440 &   4909900 &   1582    &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.5    &   5.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170329    &   1561890 &   4910980 &   1250    &   MAC &   100 &       &   32.7    &   7.9 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170330    &   1558500 &   4909390 &   1203    &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.2    &   8.4 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170331    &   1564360 &   4907210 &   1197    &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.6    &   19.7    &   23.5    &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170332    &   1571290 &   4918160 &   1080    &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.8    &   6.6 &   2.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170333    &   1570430 &   4918290 &   869 &   MAC &   95  &       &   23.6    &   5.6 &   0.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170334    &   1565530 &   4919120 &   663 &   MAC &   90  &       &   18.4    &   8.7 &   20.5    &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170335    &   1565100 &   4915610 &   586 &   MAC &   100 &       &   15.1    &   6.8 &   9.8 &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170336    &   1568760 &   4918440 &   724 &   MAC &   100 &       &   26.5    &   13.9    &   12.0    &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170337    &   1563570 &   4906190 &   1149    &   MAC &   100 &       &   24.8    &   7.5 &   1.5 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170341    &   1579920 &   4890580 &   254 &   MAC &   100 &       &   28.6    &   4.5 &   0.3 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170342    &   1579640 &   4891250 &   272 &   MAC &   100 &       &   18.8    &   11.2    &   73.8    &   -9999   &   3   \\
        20170344    &   1589220 &   4890470 &   963 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.9    &   8.0 &   1.0 &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170346    &   1572260 &   4918250 &   260 &   MAC &   100 &       &   19.3    &   12.0    &   18.8    &   -9999   &   2   \\
        20170347    &   1575560 &   4919100 &   422 &   MAC &   100 &       &   30.7    &   12.6    &   0.3 &   -9999   &       \\
        20171007    &   1592610 &   4905140 &   832 &   MAC &   100 &       &   25.1    &   6.4 &   2.8 &   50  &   2   \\
        20171015    &   1594430 &   4895710 &   333 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.7    &   12.3    &   14.5    &   35  &   3   \\
        20171016    &   1594060 &   4892390 &   728 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   40  &   3   \\
        20171017    &   1593560 &   4892350 &   728 &   MAC &   100 &       &   16.9    &   7.2 &   11.5    &   50  &   3   \\
        20171020    &   1569820 &   4908340 &   670 &   MAC &   100 &       &   27.6    &   5.0 &   0.5 &   60  &   2   \\
        20171021    &   1568030 &   4907030 &   808 &   MAC &   100 &       &   23.2    &   11.2    &   1.0 &   45  &   2   \\
        20171022    &   1567060 &   4905870 &   643 &   MAC &   50  &   40  &   17.5    &   23.8    &   38.3    &   35  &   3   \\      
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{S[table-format=8.0]S[table-format=7.0]S[table-format=7.0]c S[table-format=3.0]S[table-format=3.0] S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=-4.0]S[table-format=-4.0]S[table-format=-4.0]}
        \caption{Summary of data collected in the field for OMT fm. $R_{site(obs)}$ is the . For each geomechanical survey, its code, coordinates (in term of Longitude and
            Latitute, according to the Gauss-Boaga system), elevation, geological formation, lithology, corrected median value, interquartile range and GSI are reported. Used abbreviations: Long: longitude; Lat: latitude; Geol. fm: geological formation; Sst: sandstone; Sltst: siltstone;W.G: weathering grade.}
        \label{tab:summary_camp_OMT} \\
        \toprule
        {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} & {\thead{Elev.\\(m.a.s.l.)}}& {\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}}  & {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)}$}} & {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}}& {\textbf{$ Mv\%$}} & {\textbf{GSI}} &{\textbf{{W.G}}\\
        \midrule
        \endfirsthead
        \caption[]{}\\        
        \toprule
        {\thead{Survey site\\ code}}& {\thead{Long\\ GB (m)}}& {\thead{Lat\\ GB (m)}} & {\thead{Elev.\\(m.a.s.l.)}}& {\thead{Geol.\\ fm.}}  & {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\thead{Sltst\\(\%)}}& {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)}$}} & {\textbf{$R_{site(obs)IQR}$}}& {\textbf{$ Mv\%$}} & {\textbf{GSI}} &{\textbf{{W.G}}\\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        \multicolumn{12}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        20160060    &   1585310 &   4881500 &   345 &   OMT &       &   80  &   11.3    &   16.6    &   42  &   40  &   3   \\
        20160061    &   1585850 &   4880540 &   339 &   OMT &   30  &   70  &   17.5    &   17.2    &   32  &       &   2   \\
        20160062    &   1585380 &   4880440 &   343 &   OMT &       &   100 &   24.0    &   12.3    &   11.5    &   70  &   2   \\
        20160063    &   1585690 &   4880730 &   206 &   OMT &   10  &   90  &   21.1    &   10.0    &   9   &   55  &   2   \\
        20160092    &   1591940 &   4896490 &   530 &   OMT &   40  &   60  &   12.9    &   16.0    &   34.2    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160100    &   1587890 &   4901610 &   652 &   OMT &   70  &   30  &   4.3 &   3.1 &   79  &   30  &   3   \\
        20160101    &   1587810 &   4901210 &   635 &   OMT &       &   100 &   19.0    &   18.2    &   20  &   50  &   2   \\
        20160105    &   1593670 &   4902010 &   887 &   OMT &       &       &   11.0    &   6.9 &   34.8    &   40  &   2   \\
        20160106    &   1590890 &   4902140 &   548 &   OMT &       &   100 &   7.5 &   3.0 &   68  &   25  &   3   \\
        20160107    &   1588060 &   4903140 &   548 &   OMT &   50  &   50  &   18.8    &   16.4    &   28.7    &   40  &   2   \\
        20160108    &   1590740 &   4902810 &   682 &   OMT &       &   100 &   30.9    &   10.2    &   1.8 &   65  &   2   \\
        20160109    &   1590890 &   4903980 &   653 &   OMT &   20  &   80  &   15.1    &   6.3 &   16.8    &   45  &   2   \\
        20160110    &   1590310 &   4903550 &   822 &   OMT &   15  &   85  &   20.7    &   23.0    &   32  &   50  &   2   \\
        20160113    &   1593170 &   4901550 &   875 &   OMT &   100 &       &   4.7 &   1.7 &   83.8    &   20  &   2   \\
        20160114    &   1594060 &   4901390 &   713 &   OMT &   100 &       &   11.4    &   14.8    &   29.5    &   35  &   3   \\
        20160129    &   1585690 &   4890080 &   453 &   OMT &   10  &   90  &   17.4    &   9.3 &   25.2    &   50  &   2   \\
        20160137    &   1584700 &   4893120 &   205 &   OMT &   20  &   80  &   25.5    &   16.1    &   23  &   55  &   2   \\
        20160138    &   1585060 &   4891290 &   292 &   OMT &       &   100 &   14.4    &   19.0    &   23.8    &   55  &   2   \\
        20160139    &   1585460 &   4890900 &   349 &   OMT &   25  &   75  &   18.4    &   27.4    &   36.2    &   50  &   2   \\
        20160142    &   1581280 &   4892610 &   174 &   OMT &       &   100 &   21.3    &   20.6    &   7.2 &   55  &   2   \\
        20160164    &   1574540 &   4895330 &   392 &   OMT &   5   &   95  &   14.6    &   5.5 &   12.5    &   40  &   0   \\
        20160165    &   1574060 &   4895410 &   315 &   OMT &       &       &   10.2    &   11.6    &   45.2    &   25  &   2   \\
        20160167    &   1575370 &   4896090 &   386 &   OMT &       &   100 &   24.0    &   10.8    &   6.5 &   65  &   2   \\
        20160169    &   1573830 &   4897010 &   413 &   OMT &   10  &   90  &   12.2    &   6.8 &   29  &   40  &   2   \\
        20160182    &   1582910 &   4902440 &   386 &   OMT &       &   100 &   8.6 &   8.6 &   46.2    &   30  &   2   \\
        20160183    &   1585660 &   4903570 &   386 &   OMT &       &   100 &   18.9    &   21.9    &   23  &       &   2   \\
        20160184    &   1586030 &   4904080 &   285 &   OMT &       &   100 &   14.4    &   12.2    &   29  &   45  &   2   \\
        20160185    &   1585170 &   4905420 &   531 &   OMT &       &   100 &   18.6    &   13.1    &   24  &   50  &   2   \\
        20160186    &   1583460 &   4903170 &   461 &   OMT &       &       &   13.5    &   5.9 &   12  &   45  &   2   \\
        20160198    &   1589770 &   4909760 &   1061    &   OMT &       &   100 &   12.3    &   10.5    &   30  &   40  &   2   \\
        20160220    &   1573400 &   4914060 &   371 &   OMT &   100 &       &   9.8 &   9.3 &   33.2    &   30  &   2   \\
        20160229    &   1574330 &   4913600 &   579 &   OMT &       &   100 &   20.9    &   7.0 &   3.5 &   60  &   2   \\
        20160232    &   1580420 &   4908600 &   475 &   OMT &       &   100 &   15.4    &   10.3    &   2.5 &   45  &   2   \\
        20160233    &   1581400 &   4908640 &   594 &   OMT &   100 &       &   4.1 &   2.8 &   75.2    &   35  &   2   \\
        20160235    &   1582870 &   4909450 &   562 &   OMT &   70  &   30  &   6.3 &   12.7    &   51.2    &   40  &   2   \\
        20160238    &   1580630 &   4910180 &   464 &   OMT &       &   100 &   21.6    &   9.7 &   3   &   55  &   2   \\
        20160239    &   1574480 &   4905320 &   153 &   OMT &   20  &   80  &   18.2    &   9.8 &   24.5    &   40  &   0   \\
        20160254    &   1575710 &   4901860 &   170 &   OMT &   30  &   70  &   12.1    &   11.3    &   33.5    &   40  &   3   \\
        20160271    &   1569340 &   4919140 &   620 &   OMT &       &   100 &   20.2    &   11.2    &   10  &   60  &   2   \\
        20160273    &   1579020 &   4902060 &   136 &   OMT &       &   100 &   22.9    &   8.4 &   5.2 &   55  &   2   \\
        20160274    &   1582600 &   4907710 &   691 &   OMT &       &   100 &   22.2    &   17.2    &   25  &   55  &   2   \\
        20160275    &   1584690 &   4907730 &   702 &   OMT &       &   100 &   14.8    &   8.8 &   23.1    &   40  &   2   \\
        20160276    &   1575990 &   4908200 &   208 &   OMT &   75  &   25  &   7.5 &   15.4    &   47.2    &   35  &   2   \\
        20160282    &   1585630 &   4893040 &   296 &   OMT &       &   100 &   14.2    &   11.7    &   22.8    &   45  &   3   \\
        20160285    &   1572780 &   4919370 &   498 &   OMT &   40  &   60  &   13.8    &   13.1    &   22.8    &       &   2   \\
        20160287    &   1573630 &   4920530 &   546 &   OMT &       &   100 &   13.3    &   5.9 &   12.8    &   50  &   2   \\
        20160289    &   1579680 &   4905760 &   352 &   OMT &       &   100 &   10.9    &   10.9    &   23.2    &   25  &   3   \\
        20170345    &   1587930 &   4895320 &   802 &   OMT &       &   100 &   10.6    &   6.0 &   57.2    &       &   3   \\
        20170348    &   1593320 &   4901880 &   873 &   OMT &       &   100 &   19.2    &   9.4 &   2.5 &       &   2   \\
        20171006    &   1589040 &   4904920 &   425 &   OMT &       &   100 &   15.5    &   12.4    &   24  &   45  &   3   \\
        20171009    &   1592490 &   4902840 &   763 &   OMT &   100 &       &   4.9 &   3.4 &   79.5    &   20  &   2   \\
        20171010    &   1583330 &   4896580 &   114 &   OMT &       &   100 &   17.3    &   6.4 &   8.8 &   35  &   3   \\
        20171011    &   1585700 &   4897160 &   150 &   OMT &   100 &   100 &   11.1    &   6.5 &   31  &   40  &   3   \\
        20171012    &   1585890 &   4899870 &   439 &   OMT &       &   100 &   17.3    &   20.1    &   11.5    &   50  &   3   \\
        20171013    &   1587390 &   4898340 &   398 &   OMT &   100 &       &   8.1 &   14.4    &   52.8    &   35  &   2   \\
        20171014    &   1589350 &   4896180 &   415 &   OMT &       &   100 &   25.5    &   10.2    &   4.8 &   70  &   2   \\
        20171018    &   1589600 &   4892770 &   270 &   OMT &       &   100 &   18.2    &   13.2    &   22.5    &   35  &   3   \\
        20171019    &   1587370 &   4891140 &   340 &   OMT &       &   100 &   5.3 &   4.8 &   70.2    &   15  &   3   \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1: Low quality considering it is the 21st question.

Answer (score 3):

- All your `{\textbf{{W.G}}` are missing an `}` at the end
- `\begin{appendices}` is not completed

Next time please provide a **minimal** example, a lot of this MWE are not relevant.